# .NET prevent loading usercontrol data on default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, bigdata

I have default.aspx page and have a four user controls which contains gridview. 
I show this user controls with modalpopupextender (ajaxtoolkit), when users click on some button on default.aspx. Problem is, that all usercontrols data (actually table rows) are loaded when page is started so my page response very slow, because this gridviews contains a lot of data.

So when I run my page, click ctrl+U to get source code, there is loaded whole data from usercontrols.

My code:

**default.aspx**

```
<%@ Register Src="houseUC.ascx" TagName="house1" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
..
<uc1:house1 ID="house" runat="server" />
```

**houseUC.ascx**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

 <asp:Button ID="buttonHouse" runat="server" Text='Show all' /> //Button which appears in default.aspx where I pute <uc1:house1..>.

<cc1:ModalPopupExtender runat="server"  ID="modalHouse" TargetControlID="buttonHouse"
    PopupControlID="panelHouse" CancelControlID="closeHouse">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfModalVisible" />
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelHouse">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelZaposleni" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
button for close..
</asp:Panel/>
```

**houseUC.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        //get data from sql query..
         SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         DataSet datas = new DataSet();
         sda.Fill(datas);
         GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
         GridView1.DataBind(); //GRIDVIEW CONTAINS 300+rows
        con.Close();
}
```

So how can I manage to do that usercontrol loads when I click on button "Show All" and not before (with default.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code from the page load event into the show all  button click event.
Then create a hidden dummy Target controlID. Call the show method of the popup after loading the grid view.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenDummy" runat="server" />
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender runat="server"  ID="modalHouse" TargetControlID="HiddenDummy"
PopupControlID="panelHouse" CancelControlID="closeHouse">
```

```
     protected void ShowAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         //get data from sql query..
           SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataSet datas = new DataSet();
           sda.Fill(datas);
           GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
           GridView1.DataBind(); //GRIDVIEW CONTAINS 300+rows
           con.Close();
           modalHouse.show();
       }
```

Comment: I tried but nothing happens (popup with no gridview).

Comment: I have updated my answer.You need to show the popup from code behind in order to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I think without hidden value there is no other option to do that. Thank you for your time.